# How to see UTC time using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been using this for `Time.now` for fetching current time. But this shows current time as per my country. Now I want to see current time according to UTC How do I do that in ruby.

Comment: Could you be more specific, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I looked into few threads but couldn't find much regarding my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple. Just use

```
Time.now.utc
```

Comment: It would double the length of your answer, but consider adding `require 'time'`. I think it's helpful to newbies to include any required `require`s.